# How to add a shortcut for 'Reload Scripts'?

Tags: python, scripting, workflow, shortcut

*Blender 2.7x used to have <kbd>F8</kbd> to reload scripts.*

As an add-on developer I rely on reloading the scripts a lot and having to press <kbd>F3</kbd> and search for "Reload Scripts” every time I update the add-on I develop and that's pretty much inconvenient IMHO. I tried to add shortkey in the keymap section of the settings but it seems that 'Reload Scripts' doesn’t exist in the list of operators that can be attached to shortkeys.

**Q:** Is there any way to get <kbd>F8</kbd> back? And in general, how do I go about adding a shortkey to any other operator that is not listed in the keymap section?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

New shortcuts can be added in the preferences *Edit > Preferences > Keymap*.

With the keymap tab open, navigate to the *Window* category of shortcuts. Click the *Add New* button to create a new shortcut. The operator for reloading scripts is `bpy.ops.script.reload()` therefore the identifier for the shortcut is `script.reload`. Click on the shortcut field and press <kbd>F8</kbd> to set the key binding.

[image]

In the default keymap for Blender 2.80 there is no existing key binding on <kbd>F8</kbd> which means you can add the shortcut without any problem.

Answer (score 2):

you can add the reload scripts to Quick Favorites. Doing this, you just have to press Q button and access the Reload Scripts.
To do this, you type reload scripts in F3 search - right click in reload scripts - add to Quick Favorites
[image]

Answer (score 1):

not the best answer yet,

but you could try with these commands,

from the script-editor or console-window:

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.preferences.addon_refresh()
#
# OR: 
# (replace module name !) - first disable ... 
bpy.ops.preferences.addon_disable(module="space_view3d_align_tools")
# ... then re-enable 
bpy.ops.preferences.addon_enable( module="space_view3d_align_tools" )
```