# Having trouble creating an Addon with multiple modules

Tags: add-on

I'm trying to put together an add-on that contains two operators.  I've gotten each operator file to run properly independently, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to write an **init**.py file that would allow me to distribute them as a single add-on.

I've posted everything on Github.  The three files aren't too long:
https://github.com/blackears/blenderStairs/tree/master/src

I've read a few other threads, but nothing seems to work for me.  How can I get my **init**.py to register my operators properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The add-on registration can be simplified using a `register()` and `unregister()` function per file that can be called by the `__init__.py`. You've already implemented these to test your operators, but they can be used for the full add-on as well. Therefore all you have to do is import the `kitfoxStairs.py` and `kitfoxStairsCurved.py` and then call their `register()` function in the `__init__.py`.

```
# Copyright 2019 Mark McKay
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.


bl_info = {
    "name": "Curved Stairs Mesh Generator",
    "description": "Adds new mesh builders for quickly creating staircases.",
    "author": "Mark McKay",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 80, 0),
    "location": "View3D > Add > Mesh",
    "wiki_url": "https://github.com/blackears/blenderStairs",
    "tracker_url": "https://github.com/blackears/blenderStairs",
    "support": "COMMUNITY",
    "category": "Add Mesh"
}


import bpy
from .operators import kitfoxStairs
from .operators import kitfoxStairsCurved


def register():
    kitfoxStairs.register()
    kitfoxStairsCurved.register()


def unregister():
    kitfoxStairs.unregister()
    kitfoxStairsCurved.unregister()
```

If you want to reload modifications of your scripts when they have been imported before, then you need to *replace* the import statements

```
import bpy
from .operators import kitfoxStairs
from .operators import kitfoxStairsCurved
```

with the following code:

```
if "bpy" in locals():
    import importlib
    if "kitfoxStairs" in locals():
        importlib.reload(kitfoxStairs)
    if "kitfoxStairsCurved" in locals():
        importlib.reload(kitfoxStairs)
else:
    from .operators import kitfoxStairs
    from .operators import kitfoxStairsCurved

import bpy
```

Scripts can be reloaded through <kbd>F3</kbd> > *Reload Scripts*. Blender 2.8x doesn't have the <kbd>F8</kbd> shortcut anymore, but you can [add it to your keymap](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/155247/add-shortkey-for-reload-scripts-in-blender-2-80). Since Blender 2.83 this feature is available via the top bar menu *Blender Icon > System > Reload Scripts*.

**Note:** I've removed the `if __name__ == "__main__":` from the `__init__.py` since this doesn't work with relative imports.

---

There is an error in the `menu_func` of `kitfoxStairsCurved.py`. It should reference the `AddStairsCurved` class instead of `AddStairs`. The correct function is:

```
def menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(AddStairsCurved.bl_idname, icon='MESH_CUBE')
```

Comment: I've made the changes you suggested, but my module is still not loading.  Worse, it seems to be failing silently without any meaningful error messages.  I've pushed my updates to the repository.

Comment: @kitfox works fine for me. Have you installed the add-on by zipping the src folder and then installing it through *Edit > Preferences > Add-ons*?

Comment: I was trying to run it by trying to install the [code]__init__.py[/code] file as an addon.  Zipping it first seemed to work.  Is there a way to run it in an unzipped state?  Also, what the best directory structure within the zip?

Comment: If you don't want to .zip it, you could also create a new directory, e.g. kitfox, where Blender's add-ons are stored `[blender version]/scripts/addons` (replace the x with the actual version, e.g. 2.81) and copy the `__init__.py` and the modules into kitfox (or however you called the directory).

Answer (score 1):

Basically for an addon, import as a module, call the modules register method to enable.

The folder your addon is in is the module name, eg `mesh_stairs`

The operators you have in the operators folder already have a register and unregister method. Can `from ./operators import foo` and in register call `foo.register()`  (*as answered by @RJG while I was dawdling along*)

**Dynamically loading each module in operators folder.**

```
mesh_stairs/
    __init__.py
    operators/
        __init__.py
        foo.py
        bar.py
```

Here is a method I played around with for `bat_tools`  to manage a number of  "addons" into one. *Enabling / disabling addons for workspaces has prompted somewhat of a rethink.*

Pretty generic. Using `__all__` and globals. Could load any list or dict etc instead.

Script: `mesh_stairs/operators/__init__.py`

```
"""
BATTOOLS edit re stairs q.
"""

__all__ = []


def register_tools():
    """ """
    for name in __all__:
        register_tool(globals()[name])


def register_tool(tool):
    """

    :param tool:

    """
    print("REGTOOLS", tool)
    tool.register()


def unregister_tools():
    """ """
    for name in __all__:
        unregister_tool(globals()[name])


def unregister_tool(tool):
    """

    :param tool:

    """
    print("UNREGTOOLS", tool)
    tool.unregister()



def load_tools():
    """ """
    __all__.clear()
    import pkgutil

    for m in pkgutil.iter_modules(__path__):
        tool = __import__(m.name, globals(), level=1)
        __all__.append(m.name)



load_tools()
```

Print in system console after enabling addon.

```
REGTOOLS <module 'mesh_stairs.operators.kitfoxStairs' from '/home/batfinger/.config/blender/2.82/scripts/addons/mesh_stairs/operators/kitfoxStairs.py'>
REGTOOLS <module 'mesh_stairs.operators.kitfoxStairsCurved' from '/home/batfinger/.config/blender/2.82/scripts/addons/mesh_stairs/operators/kitfoxStairsCurved.py'>
```

Script: `mesh_stairs/__init__.py`

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Curved Stairs Mesh Generator",
    "description": "Adds new mesh builders for quickly creating staircases.",
    "author": "Mark McKay",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 80, 0),
    "location": "View3D > Add > Mesh",
#    "warning": "", # used for warning icon and text in addons panel
    "wiki_url": "https://github.com/blackears/blenderStairs",
    "tracker_url": "https://github.com/blackears/blenderStairs",
    "support": "COMMUNITY",
    "category": "Add Mesh"
}


from . import operators

def register():
    operators.register_tools()



def unregister():
    operators.unregister_tools()
```