# Using Multiple Python Files in an Addon

Tags: python

Im not THAT experienced in Blender Python but i think this is something confusing.c
I want to use multiple files for an addon and im not able to.
I dont understand what am i supposed to do
Am i supposed to just import the class in **init** and do nothing with it and register it in the same file as the class , or am i supposed to register the classes in the init
even if i do one of them , the relative import doesnt work
if i do `from .AddCube import *`
it says `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package Error: Python script failed, check the message in the system console`

Comment: Speculate you are running from the text editor _ie_  `__name__ = "__main__"`  to get this error (as opposed to not having the relative submodules?) Have mentioned a work around to this here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/183773/trying-to-make-a-menu-using-multiple-modules/183817#183817  using absolute imports based on your addon name, to make testing in text editor possible.   See also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/158775/having-trouble-creating-an-addon-with-multiple-modules

Comment: @batFINGER thankyou , that was absolutely what i wanted