# How to run python script with multiple files from console?

Tags: command-line

I want to run a python script in Blender via the console, but I split the script into multiple files. The folder consists of two files, "main.py" and "poser.py". I call the main script like this:

```
blender -b --python E:\Development\Python\BlenderPoser\main.py
```

But I get the following error when trying to import the "poser.py" file:

```
Error: Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "E:\Development\Python\BlenderPoser\main.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import poser
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

What I get from this is that Blender only imports the main.py file, and ignores all of the rest. How can I tell Blender to also import the rest of the files?

Comment: If I'm not mistaking, you should write something like `from poser import <module name, or class>`

Comment: Does this help? [Having trouble creating an Addon with multiple modules](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/158775/having-trouble-creating-an-addon-with-multiple-modules)

Comment: Using "from poser import Poser" results in the message "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'poser'".
And I do know how to create a modular plugin, but I would like to create a script without making it a full plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding the additional files into a separate folder and adding that folder to the system path:

```
# Add the folder to the system path, so it can be loaded by the script
main_dir = pathlib.Path(os.path.dirname(__file__)).resolve()
core_dir = os.path.join(main_dir, "core")
sys.path.append(str(core_dir))
```

After this, I am able to import the poser.py file with `import poser`